# How to open email composer with attachment in titanium?

Tags: titanium, titanium-mobile, titanium-alloy

I am making application in IOS and Android using titanium .I want to open email composer (having some attachment) on button click.can you please tell me how  can I do in IOS and Android.?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Directly from the [documentation.](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.EmailDialog) This assumes you already have created your button.

```
button.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    // Create email window
    var emailDialog = Ti.UI.createEmailDialog();
    emailDialog.subject = "Hello from Titanium";
    emailDialog.toRecipients = ['foo@yahoo.com'];
    emailDialog.messageBody = '<b>Appcelerator Titanium Rocks!</b>';
    // Add attachment
    var f = Ti.Filesystem.getFile('cricket.wav');
    emailDialog.addAttachment(f);
    // Open the window
    emailDialog.open();
});
```